# Are there any default model topics?

Tags: gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I made a model for a Pioneer 3AT Mobile robot and looked at the output from 'gztopic list' but I only found one related topic:

> /gazebo/default/Pioneer3AT/joint_cmd

1. Is there an example of how to publish to the /joint_cmd topic?
2. Are there any other default topics available such as a /joint_state or /pose available?
3. Do I need to write a model plugin to implement those functions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1515/are-there-any-default-model-topics?/) by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3b71414a1c761150cc84fda2f2cd9220f9296f64/plugins/DiffDrivePlugin.cc?at=default) is an example of a Gazebo plugin for controlling a vehicle with joints.

To publish to Gazebo topics, you can make use of gazebo transport. See this [example](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/custom_messages#Request_Publisher_Executable) on how to write a program that publishes to gazebo topics (the example uses custom msgs which should not be needed in your case). Supported msg descriptions can be found [here](http://gazebosim.org/msgs/1.4.0/classes.html)

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-02**:
Also, the joint_cmd topics are used by the Joint Control widget on the right hand side of the gazebo window.